# data in txt file overwritten

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

the program is supposed to create a number of blank records to a .txt file, which can be edited later to add infos like name and balance..etc. my problem is whenever i put another record, the balance from the first account disappears (but the name doesn't). if i try to add another account, the balance from the previous account disappear as well. its probably overwritten or something.

how do i fix this?

```
import java.io.*;

public class CreateBankFile {
   private RandomAccessFile file;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      CreateBankFile blank = new CreateBankFile();
   }

   public CreateBankFile() throws IOException{
      initialize();
      int task = 0;
      while(task == 0)
      {
         writeRecord();
      }
   }

   private void initialize() {
      Account acc = new Account();

      try {
         File fileName = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/x/Desktop/hehe.txt");
         file = new RandomAccessFile( fileName, "rw" );

         // Create 100000 blank records in the file
         for ( int i = 0; i < 100001; i++)
            acc.write( file );
      } catch ( IOException ioex ){
         System.out.println("File does not exists");
      }
   }

    private void writeRecord() throws IOException {
       Account acc = new Account();
       BufferedReader data = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       System.out.println("Enter Account # ");
       String accNo = data.readLine();
       int recordNumber = Integer.parseInt(accNo);

       try {

          File fileName = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/x/Desktop/hehe.txt");
          file = new RandomAccessFile( fileName, "rw" );

          // Write the record to the file
          if ( recordNumber > 0 && recordNumber < 100001 ) {

             System.out.println("Enter Account Name: ");
             String neym = data.readLine();
             System.out.println("Enter Remaining Balance: ");
             String numbah = data.readLine();
             acc.setName(neym);
             acc.setBalance(numbah);

             // Go to the record location
             file.seek( (recordNumber - 1) * acc.size() );

             // Write the record out
             acc.write( file );

             System.out.println("\nUpdate Succesful!\n");
             System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
          }
       } catch ( Exception ioex ){
          System.out.println("File does not exists");
       }
   }
}


class Account {
   private String name;
   private String balance;

   // Constructor
   public Account() { this ("", ""); }

   // Overloaded Constructor
   public Account(String n, String b) {
      name = n;
      balance = b;
   }

   // Public method to read the data from the file
   public void read( RandomAccessFile file ) throws IOException {
      setName( padData( file ) );
      setBalance ( padData( file ) );
   }

   // Public method to write the data to the file
   public void write( RandomAccessFile file ) throws IOException {
      writeData( file, getName() );
      writeData( file, getBalance() );
   }

   // The method that actually writes the data to the file

   private void writeData(RandomAccessFile f, String n) throws IOException {
      StringBuffer buf = null;

      if ( n != null )
         buf = new StringBuffer( n );
      else
         buf = new StringBuffer( 20 );
         buf.setLength( 20 );
         f.writeChars( buf.toString() );
   }

   // This pads the data so to make the data all the same size
   // we will go for a size of 20
   private String padData( RandomAccessFile f ) throws IOException {
      char data[] = new char[ 20 ], temp;

      for ( int i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
         temp = f.readChar();
         data[ i ] = temp;
      }

      return new String ( data ).replace( '\0', ' ' );
   }

   // This method hard codes the value for the size of the record
   // which is 20
   public static int size() { return 20; }

   // The get and set methods
   public void setName(String n) { name = n; }

   public void setBalance(String b) { balance = b; }

   public String getName() { return name; }

   public String getBalance() { return balance; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to go through your file operations step-by-step?

Comment: Before you get too much invested in this solution, let me point out, that your solution depends on all 'records' in your text file being exactly the same length. The minute a user opens that file up in Notepad or some other text editor, all bets are off. In fact, the way you have written the program, only one 'line' will exist, since there are no new-lines or crlf pairs at the end of each fixed-length record / line. Seems to me that what you are trying to achieve could be done using a spreadsheet, no code necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from any other issues that others are pointing out.

```
   buf.setLength( 20 );
```

you're only writing out 20 chars. You also need braces on your if statement:

```
private void writeData(RandomAccessFile f, String n) throws IOException {
  StringBuffer buf = null;

  if ( n != null )
     buf = new StringBuffer( n );
  else {
     buf = new StringBuffer( 20 );
     buf.setLength( 20 );
  }

  f.writeChars( buf.toString() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
// Create 100000 blank records in the file
for ( int i = 0; i < 100001; i++)
    acc.write( file );
```

You have that in your `initialize()` function, which is called in `CreateBankFile()` which is called in `main()`

So every time you run your program, the file is re-initialized. Wiped out.  So, remove that code and your program should work.

(although you'll have to initialize the file the first time, maybe make a second program to initialize the file or have that be a user option, or detect to see if the file exists and initialize it if it's not already there.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely not an expert, but I do see some errors in your code. In this line you set the file pointer to point to the desired record:

```
// Go to the record location
file.seek( (recordNumber - 1) * acc.size() );
```

However, in your account class, you set the field size to 20:

```
public static int size() { return 20; }
```

A closer look at the java API reveals that the writeChars method you use here -

```
 private void writeData(RandomAccessFile f, String n) throws IOException {
  StringBuffer buf = null;

  if ( n != null )
     buf = new StringBuffer( n );
  else
     buf = new StringBuffer( 20 );
     buf.setLength( 20 );
     f.writeChars( buf.toString() );
```

}

are written as a series of chars, which, and here's the important part, are each written as a two-byte value.  Now, when you set the pointer to a specific record the seek value *is in bytes* not in chars.  therefore when you open a file and set the pointer to a specific record greater than the first record, you are overwriting data because the actual size of your fields is 40, not 20 (Remember bytes, not chars).  Hope I helped.